# Comparision gone wrong, or, how could this be false?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just randomly discovered the following in Node.js

```
0.3 + 0.2 === 0.5
true

0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3
false
```

Anyone does have an explanation for what goes on here?
The tested version is `Node.js v6.9.1` on a `4.4.0-57-generic` kernel.
Cheers to anyone able to explain this to me!

Comment: Lovely yes, I'll study this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point values are represented with powers of two. .1 and .2 can't be represented as sums of a finite number of powers of two, and so there are some inaccuracies with the addition of them. Same goes for .3, but as luck would have it the inaccuracies balanced out in the first case. More detailed description here.
http://0.30000000000000004.com/